# Datatype dataTime insertion in ontology with SPARQL queries

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, ontology

I am manually trying to insert the data in owl file with following SPARQL command:

```
qry = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/tempsensor#>" + 
       "INSERT DATA" +
           "{" + 
 ":ind1 :locatedIn :Delhi ;" + ":onDate "+ "2014-10-01T00:10:10"^^xsd:dateTime +" ;" + ":measures 13 ;" + " :hasUnit Celsius   ." + "}" ;
        UpdateAction.parseExecute(qry,ontmod);
```

On running, I am getting exception:

```
Encountered " <INTEGER> "10 "" at line 1, column 96. Was expecting one of:
"graph" ...
"}" ...
";" ...
"," ...
"." ...
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11Update._parse(ParserSPARQL11Update.java:78)
```

How should I format datetime so that sparql will allow to execuate the query.
Ontology used is give at [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loneharoon/Semantics/master/temperatureSensor.owl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print your created query string you should quickly be able to see that it is invalid i.e.

```
System.out.println(qry);
```

The problem is that you haven't put quotes around your date time constant as is required for literals in SPARQL.

So your update needs to look more like this:

```
qry = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/tempsensor#>\n" + 
      "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\n" +
      "INSERT DATA\n" +
      "{\n" + 
      ":ind1 :locatedIn :Delhi ;\n" + 
      ":onDate \"2014-10-01T00:10:10\"^^xsd:dateTime ;\n" + 
      ":measures 13 ;" + " :hasUnit Celsius .\n" + 
      "}" ;
```

Note the need to use `\"` to escape the quotes so Java doesn't interpret them as the start/end of a string.

I also added `\n` i.e. newlines into your string as this will help the parser give you a more meaningful error message with a more precise error location than the `line 1, column 96` you get with the existing query.

Generally if you need to inject constants into a query/update you are better off using the [Parameterized SPARQL String](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/parameterized-sparql-strings.html) support in Jena which is considerably less error prone and not vulnerable to SPARQL injection as your current approach is.

Comment: I tried accordingly, but it is throwing exception as:                                          'Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryException: Line 5, column 32: Unresolved prefixed name: xsd:dateTime
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11Update._parse(ParserSPARQL11Update.java:90)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11Update.parse$(ParserSPARQL11Update.java:45)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.UpdateParser.parse(UpdateParser.java:42)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateFactory.make(UpdateFactory.java:88)
'

Comment: @haroonrashid The error message pretty clearly describes the problem:  **"Unresolved prefixed name: xsd:dateTime"**.  You probably didn't include the **xsd:** prefix.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've updated my answer to add in the missing prefix definition though as you point out the original query did not include it

Comment: @RobV Yes, I don't think the fault was on your end, really;  it was missing from the original.  There have been a number of questions popping up lately that seem to point to a bit of "not reading the [documentation,error message]".